# Subwoofer in a 5.1 surround Possible with outputs?

Tags: home-theater, speakers, audio

I am collecting speakers for a 5.1 surround!

Now I have found a subwoofer which looks nice it's an active subwoofer.

But it has this connections:

[image]

it has stereo input and output for speakers!
My surround receiver has an subwoofer jack output, so only subwoofer signal.
Can I still use it in my surround set?

I Hope you guys can help!

Comment: I would think that you could connect them with a 2.5mm male to male cable. But as I don't know what type of jack your surround receiver has as its subwoofer output, I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to connect this to your subwoofer output. The presence of the speaker outs means it has internal crossover networks to route the lowest frequencies from both channels to the sub while passing higher frequencies along to the other speakers. The fact that your receiver has already performed that separation means the crossover isn't needed... but it shouldn't do any harm.